# SSL insecure objects

Tags: html, security, ssl

On my page https://ol-shop.at/index.php?route=account/login it seems to be that there are insecure objects. Could someone please help me, taking a look on the source code. I don't know which url or object could be insecure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps http://ol-shop.at/image/secure_site2.gif?

This source:
TrustLogo("http://ol-shop.at/image/secure_site2.gif", "SC4", "none");

Comment: Taking examples from the TrustLogo website, I'd change that line to:
TrustLogo("/image/secure_site2.gif", "SC4", "none");